# How to align the image in center inside a div using Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap i.e. v4.0.0-beta.3 and I've an image which is located inside a div tag whose height is fixed and I want to align the image in the absolute center of the div tag. Although I'm able to align the image in horizontal center using `mx-auto` and `d-block` classes but for the vertical alignment, I'm unable to do so even after following the methods from many stackoverflow answers like [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwj06fWTob7YAhWHQI8KHS5xDeYQFgg6MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F43226511%2Fhow-can-i-center-an-image-in-bootstrap-v4-alpha%2F43227280&usg=AOvVaw0pjZh2_oJK42tdeSKBkLj1) and [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwj06fWTob7YAhWHQI8KHS5xDeYQFghAMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F44055130&usg=AOvVaw0cqaxp013qlkDCeWOMzcZb). Here is the code.

```css
.border-section {
  border: 2px solid #D0D0D0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 mr-4 border-section" style="height:290px">
      <img class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="View">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You may want to consider how you would leverage Bootstrap's `flex-box` classes, see: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#align-items

Comment: There's no reason for extra CSS. Just use the Bootstrap flex util classes: https://www.codeply.com/go/Niu8NCcdqj

Comment: @ZimSystem, I don't understand why your code is not working properly in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
.border-section {
  border: 2px solid #D0D0D0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 mr-4 border-section" style="height:290px">
      <img class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="View">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well it works but it's a bit out of context ... we need to use bootstrap and no general CSS styling